# Compare two dates in smarty

Tags: php, date, smarty

I have two dates in respective format (02-Dec-14 and 17-Dec-14 ) and i want to compare these two dates in smarty.

How can i compare these two dates ? please help.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: did you try anything by yourself??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have those dates assigned to Smarty for example this way:

```
$smarty->assign('date2','02-Dec-14');
$smarty->assign('date1','17-Dec-14');
```

you can use `strtotime` function directly in Smarty, for example:

```
{if $date1|strtotime < $date2|strtotime}
    {$date1} is earlier than {$date2}
{elseif $date1|strtotime == $date2|strtotime}
    Both dates are the same
{else}
    {$date2} is earlier than {$date1}
{/if}
```

Comment: Note that this may require you to change Smarty's [security settings](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security), in particular the `$php_modifiers` setting.

Comment: @IMSoP True, but only when you enable Security in Smarty. By default it's not enabled so you can probably use all PHP functions/modifiers

Comment: Yeah, just thought it was worth mentioning as a "gotcha" if someone tries this and it doesn't work.

Comment: @IMSoP  Yeah, that's true. We don't know what's the OP's code here - maybe some 3rd party code with Security enabled

Comment: Thanks guys , i made it custom plugin inside lib folder and then just call them in to template file     {$smarty.now|strtotime|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}

Comment: Using php-function "strtotime" as a modifier is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Answer (score 4):

```
{if {$date1|date_format:"%y%m%d"} lt {$date2|date_format:"%y%m%d"}}
```

Comment: it works fine unless your second date is after 100 years, then u might be better of using %Y%m%d instead of %y (2021 instead of just 21)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$d = '02-Dec-14';
$e = '17-Dec-14';
$t1 = strtotime($d);
$t2 = strtotime($e);
/*  
// Test if it works.
if ($t2 > $t1) {
    echo 'second is greater';
}
*/
```

You can then assign it to Smarty:

```
$this->assign('date_one', $t1);
$this->assign('date_two', $t2);
```

And in Smarty, you can compare:

```
{if $date_one < $date_rwo}
   ...do something..
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Tried many ways, could not get the solution. finally I tried something like this:
In PHP passing 2 variables something like this to smarty:

```
$insuranceStartDate= date("jS F Y", strtotime($startdate));
$smarty->assign('insuranceStartDate' , $insuranceStartDate);
$insuranceStartDatePlain= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($startdate));
$smarty->assign('insuranceStartDatePlain' , $insuranceStartDatePlain);
```

In smarty comparing like below:

```
{if $insuranceStartDatePlain|date_format:'%Y/%m/%d' < '2017/09/01'} 
less than -  1<sup>st</sup> Septemeber 2017
{else}
greater  - {$insuranceStartDate}
{/if}
```

Note:to compare dates when they are strings, use order YYYY/MM/DD in smarty

Hope it helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my smarty function (add to your smarty plugin directory):

```
/* 
* Smarty plugin 
* ------------------------------------------------------------- 
* Type: function 
* Name: date_diff 
* Author: Rafał Pawlukiewicz
* Purpose: factor difference between two dates in days, weeks, or years
* Input: d1 = "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" or "yyyy-mm-dd"
*        d2 = "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" or "yyyy-mm-dd" or $smarty.now
*        assign = name of variable to assign difference to 
*        interval = "days" (default), "weeks", "years" 
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20"}
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20" d2=2020-02-10 interval="weeks"}
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20" d2=2020-02-10 assign="variable_diff"} result: {$variable_diff}
* -------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function smarty_function_date_diff($params, &$smarty)
{
    $d1          = isset($params['d1']) ? $params['d1'] : date('Y-m-d');
    $d2          = isset($params['d2']) ? $params['d2'] : date('Y-m-d');
    $assign_name = isset($params['assign']) ? $params['assign'] : '';

    $date1 = strtotime($d1);
    $date2 = strtotime($d2);

    // use current for empty string
    if (! $date1) {
        $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    if (! $date2) {
        $date2 = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    $interval = isset($params['interval']) ? $params['interval'] : 'days';

    // diff in days
    $diff = ($date2 - $date1) / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if ($interval === "weeks") {
        $diff /= 7;
    }
    elseif ($interval === "years") {
        $diff /= 365.25;
    }

    $diff = floor($diff);

    if ($assign_name) {
        $smarty->assign($assign_name, $diff);
    }
    else {
        return $diff;
    }

}
```