# How to compare two time values in Smarty

Tags: php, time, smarty

I am using smarty. I would like to check two time values. It is not working well. What I have done is shown below, but it is not entering the else condition.

```
eg:
     stime = 10:30
     nowtime = current time(00:00 format)
 { if stime < nowtime}
    <li id="rv{$idx+1}" style ="display:none">test</li>
    {else}
   <li id="rv{$idx+1}" style ="display:block">test2</li>
    {/if}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates in smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250242/compare-two-dates-in-smarty)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your time into no. using **strtotime()** function

```
$stime  = strtotime("12:30");
$endtime = strtotime("11:30");

if($stime < $endtime){
     //Your logic goes here
     //<li id="rv{$idx+1}" style ="display:none">test</li>
}else{
     //Your logic goes here
     //<li id="rv{$idx+1}" style ="display:block">test2</li>
}
```