# If statment with date create in smart php

Tags: php, laravel, smarty, smarty3

How can I create a validation in smarty php, allowing the value to appear if it is within 30 days of the specified date?

In array:

```
Array (4)
0 => Array (13)
  id => 6496
  invoicenum => 6496
  datecreated => "08/09/2020"
  normalisedDateCreated => "2020-09-08"
```

I don't know what would be the ideal field for this, but we can use `datecreated` or `normalisedDateCreated`.

It would look something like this:

```
{if $invoice.datecreated ... } if it is more than 30 days from the current date it should display NO
    YES
{else}
    NO
{/if}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in your template? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250242/compare-two-dates-in-smarty help you?

Comment: Hmm.. No, because there he has two specific dates, I need for an interval of 30 days from the current date.

Comment: You can use the DateTime class with the `diff()` method - `if ((new DateTime)->diff(new DateTime($invoice['normalisedDateCreated ']))->days > 30)`

Comment: @Qirel Dont work with smarty php.

Comment: "Dont work" is so vague its impossible to help troubleshoot. That *does* work, its native PHP. Without any error messages, its really impossible to say why it "dont work". Perhaps it should be `$invoice[0]['normalisedDateCreated']`, but this is basic PHP and I would expect that you at least try to figure out what isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to solve it this way: `{if strtotime($invoice.normalisedDateCreated) > strtotime('-30 days')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current date using `$smarty.now` and then subtract days 30 from that.

```
{if "$smarty.now -30 Days"|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d' < $invoice.normalisedDateCreated}
    YES
{else}
    NO
{/if}
```

But it would be simplified if can just pass another variable from php which is 30 days prior to current date.

Another solution proposed by @zecaluis

```
{if strtotime($invoice.normalisedDateCreated) > strtotime('-30 days')}
```

Comment: His answer worked as it should in this way: `{if "$smarty.now -30 Days"|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d' < $invoice.normalisedDateCreated}`

Comment: Great friend, helping me again .. I found another solution before you insert your answer: `{if strtotime($invoice.normalisedDateCreated) > strtotime('-30 days')}`

Comment: Nice one and thank you for pointing me out the `if` keyword was missing. Updated the comparison operator too.

Comment: The sign of comparison is also in reverse, the correct one would be: `<`. At least this way it worked for me.

Comment: Brother, you have no idea of the work around  that I did in that other problem, I sent you a print in chat if you want to see how the final result was. Haha Thanks again..