# How to compare two different date AND timestamps in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I can't find a solution to this:

I only want to compare two date and timestamps with eachother like this ->

```
 {if $CONFIG.ENDDATE lte $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d %H:%M"}
```

$CONFIG.ENDDATE and  $smarty.now are Strings (Like this: string(14) "20231218 16:02"). Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I imagined it would. Does anyone have any ideas or tips?

I tried it with this Post [Compare two dates in smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250242/compare-two-dates-in-smarty)

but this does not work with timestamps. If I only use this:

```
{if $CONFIG.ENDDATE lte $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d"}
```

and only compare dates, then everything works as it should.

Comment: This feels like business logic. Could you do this in your controller (in PHP) and pass the flag to the template as a boolean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates in smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250242/compare-two-dates-in-smarty)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string, you must change `$CONFIG.ENDDATE` to timestamp.

you can try this, it will work:

```
{if $CONFIG.ENDDATE lte $smarty.now}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem like this:

```
{if $CONFIG.ENDDATE|strtotime lte $smarty.now}
```